# How can we find the clock frequency (SCK) set by master from slave in SPI

Tags: spi, clock, clock-speed

How can we (in software, no probing using CRO) know what *clock frequency the Master applies* from slave (assuming I have no prior information of this).

In general I program the Div_Reg register and I Know the X-Tal/Bus frequency, hence `clock rate = In_CLK/Div_Reg`.

Comment: It might be worth adding some more context on the type of microcontroller you're using and why you're trying to determine it?

Comment: ARM Cortex-M3/M4 would be my slave, I have no information about the master.

Comment: Either the master clock frequency is compatible with the slave and it works, or the frequency is too high and it doesn't work. Why is it important to know the exact frequency?

Comment: SPI protocol clock frequency has been boiled down to a few specific frequencies so the designer has a choice on which one to choose.  If a controller supports SPI, then you can be confident that it will accept the communication frequencies.  There are "Fast" SPI modes from some companies that have a much faster SPI clock, those are the ones that you'll need to worry about.

Comment: Perhaps you could generate interrupts and time stamp beginning and end of byte transfer to get an idea of the **average** clock speed. I don't think there's any way to know exactly- the hardware is not so instrumented to make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

If the clock signals are coming in extremely fast (say 25 MHz) then it will be a challenge to do any timing in firmware since two consecutive low to high edges will only be 40 ns apart, and processing two interrupts in that time (with the overhead of the interrupt itself, probably saving and restoring at least one register, plus reading a timer and saving it off, all in 20 ns) is not going to happen with a Cortex-M3/M4 (which, as far as I can tell, has a maximum clock speed of 180 MHz, so one instruction takes at least one 5.5 ns).

However the ARM Cortex-M3/M4 has a timer co-processor that includes a input capture section.  Assuming you can reconfigure the SCK line as an input, and route it to the input capture section, you should be able to capture two successive edges.  (I am not familiar enough with the ARM Cortex-M3/M4 architecture to know if you can route the SCK lead to the input capture input internally; if not, you could tie the two leads together externally.)